# Bootstrap 4 theming set of gray variables

Tags: bootstrap-4, sass

I don't understand how to use Bootstrap 4 set of gray variables.
In the documents it says:

> An expansive set of gray variables and a Sass map in scss/_variables.scss for consistent shades of gray across your project.

But how do I use it to style things?

I tried:

```
<div style="color:gray('600')">Test</div>
```

The text displays as white

I tried:

```
<div class="text-gray-600">Test</div>
```

The text displays as white

So I really don't understand how to use it.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

you can only use these variables inside *.scss files, not as CSS class in HTML tag (div)

example:

```
.custom-div {
  color: $gray-100;
}
```